# AWS AppRunner with outgoing traffic to VPC cannot connect to AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-ses, amazon-app-runner

In my current project, I am using **AWS AppRunner** to expose an **HTTP RESTful API** (dockerized Python with FastAPI). The AppRunner uses **AWS RDS PostgreSQL** database, **AWS S3**, and **AWS SES**, to send some emails.

In the project's staging environment **everything works perfectly**, **with a fully public AppRunner, and RDS** instances. The AppRunner uses a custom IAM role using existent full access policies to access both RDS, S3, and SES, (AmazonRDSDataFullAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess, AmazonSESFullAccess, AWSAppRunnerServicePolicyForECRAccess), in addition to service access to AWS ECR to load the API image from (i.e., latest dockerized Python with FastAPI).

**The problem** arises when creating the production environment and **moving production's database** (i.e., AWS RDS PostgreSQL) **to a private subnet**. As a consequence, the **AWS AppRunner's outgoing traffic must be connected to the VPC**, and a security group added to allow PostgreSQL traffic connecting to private database's port 5432. An S3 VPC endpoint, with the corresponding security group, is also added to allow connecting AppRunner with AWS S3. The AppRunner VPC Connector, used to connect the AppRunner with the VPC (the only one in the project), is connected to all subnets (both private and public) and uses all the specified security groups. That way, the AppRunner is able to connect and normally use both AWS S3 and RDS database. However, anytime the AppRunner tries to connect with AWS SES it get hungs until a Gateway Timeout is triggered and an HTTP 502 Bad Gateway is obtained.

In order to configure the access from AppRunner, with outgoing traffic to VPC, and the AWS SES, I created first a **security group** and then a **VPC endpoint for SES**, as explained [here] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html), but with no luck. Unfortunatelly, no logs are dumped in the AppRunner once it starts trying to connect with SES, although both my application and boto3 library do. I have tried to, at least test the connectivity from the private subnet to the AWS SES VPC endpoint, using telnet (telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 465), confirming that there is connectivity.

Do I have to use an IAM role with another policy, apart from the above specified (including AmazonSESFullAccess) ? Do I have to add any rule to the route table of either my public or private subnets?

I would really appreciate any insight regarding why the AppRunner cannot connect to the AWS SES.
Thanks in advance.

P.S: The AWS SES is still in the sandbox.

P.S1: All configuration has been manually done using AWS Console.

P.S2: I had to add a rule to my private subnet's route table to reach AWS S3, using AWS S3 managed prefixed list to route traffic to the AWS S3 VPC endpoint. I tried to do something similar with AWS SES but it seems there is no managed prefixed list (pl-) for AWS SES and CIDR are not allowed to be directly used in route tables with VPC endpoints.

These are my two route tables :

```
Private subnets Route table


pl-6<HASH1>a    vpce-091<HASH2>a
0.0.0.0/0       nat-067<HASH3>3 
172.31.0.0/16   local


Public subnets Route table (principal)

0.0.0.0/0       igw-072<HASH4>4
172.31.0.0/16   local
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to EC2 and click on Network Interface. You will see a "fargate" interface type network interface. This is created when you created that App Runner private VPC. Associate an elastic IP to it and redeploy your app. You should get internet access after that.

Comment: Sidenote: No IPv6 support yet for this, so even if you have enabled ipv6 in your subnet you won't have internet access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, user3992. Although I do not understand what is the relation between EC2 and AppRunner, I followed your advise and associated an elastic IP to the fargate interface of one of the private subnets my AppRunner is connected to. My AppRunner is connected to all the subnets in my VPC, 5 private and 4 public. Then, I redeployed my app. Unfortunatelly, that didn't work, and I still experience the same Gateway timeout. Any idea about what could be wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you may need to associate elastic IPs to all of the private subnets  you are connected. In my testing environment, I only have 1 private subnet associated with my App Runner, so it just worked when I associated the elastic IP with that subnet.

Comment: I also thought that way, so I tried to associate the same elastic IP to all the private subnets, but it seems you need a different elastic IP for each ENI you want to associate. Since I am setting up a production environment I need multiple private subnets, so it would involve paying for additional elastic IPs (IIRC we only have 1 free elastic IP). But your experience and advice is my best clue right now, so I will try it out, reducing to only 1 private subnet to test it in my environ. I will let you know what happens. Again, many thanks for your support @user3992